# Laravel: Nesting two foreach statements, Select field with Optgroups

Tags: php, laravel-4

I want to create a select field with optgroups

```
$spec = DB::table('agentspec')->orderBy('category', 'desc')->get();
```

The table has three columns

```
category, spec, agentdesc
```

The optgroup label is "category" with "spec" as the select value

This is what I've tried
getting error
Trying to get property of non-object

```
@foreach($spec as $spec)
    @if ($spec->category == 'Agent')
<optgroup label="Agent">
 @foreach($spec as $spec)
<option value="{{ $spec->spec}}">{{ $spec->spec }}{{ $spec->agentdesc }}</option>
@endforeach
    </optgroup>
 @endif
       @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rename your iterator variable here, it can't be in par with the collection:

```
@foreach($spec as $spec)
```

Comment: I;ve tried that @foreach($spec as $row)
<option value="{{ $row->spec}}">{{ $row->spec }}{{ $row->agentdesc }}</option>
@endforeach  still doesn't work Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Did you change it in both `foreach` loops?

Comment: ok i changed both and it works but not getting the results i want